# Nexus 4 Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER not working

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, nexus-4

I am trying to use the accelerometer and the magnetic field sensor on my Nexus 4 but it is not working 
I am using the following code...

```
protected Sensor compass;
protected Sensor accelerometer;
protected SensorManager sensorManager;

sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    compass = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    try {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, compass, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        Log.d(TAG, "Registered CompassSensorWatcher");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("could not register listener", e.toString());


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // Logger.d("sensor changed "+event);
    // we use TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD to get changes in the direction, but use SensorManager to get directions
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
        return;

    // Gets the value of the sensor that has been changed
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        gravity = event.values.clone();
        Log.d(TAG, "Accelerometer onSensorChanged() ");
        Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(gravity[0]) );
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        geomag = event.values.clone();

        break;
    }
}
```

I am able to get the magnetic sensor values fine... but NOT the accelerometer values...

I tried this on multiple handsets... but the issues seems to be arising only on my Nexus 4 !! 
I tried on my  Samsung S4 it worked fine on that .. but not on Nexus 4...

Nexus 4 uses Android 4.3 .

Then I upgraded to Android 4.4.2 but still the accelerometer didnt work ..

I have tried using several other apps from Play store that use accelerometer(SensorBox) .. it worked 
fine on Nexus 4 but not my code...

I also have put this in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass" />
```

Still the problem seems to be only with Nexus 4 ...

Its surprising how I can use the Magnetic sensor fine.. but not the Accelerometer ! 
Can anyone please suggest something ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after flashing my phone more than 5 times ..I found the solution.. 
This problem is a known issue :
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=62876

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/b0duELH-tV0

**Solved the issue by downgrading my Nexus to 4.2.2**

Here are the downgrade instructions :
http://www.cultofandroid.com/46632/downgrade-nexus-4-to-android-4-3-jelly-bean-from-kitkat/2/
(You can follow same instructions for 4.2.2)

I tried Android 4.3 , 4.4.2 .. CyanogenMod 4.4.2   ... The sensor event call for Accelerometer was just not working...

As soon as I downgraded to 4.2.2 .. It started working fine...

It seems some bug/driver issue that Google has still not fixed !